# Convert Spark DF[string] into Json using scala

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

Am having DataFrame with 1 column as String .

sample String :  The below content is completely stored as Single line string inside the DataFrame

```
[{"id":"2ac3a7d6-46d8-4903-8a92-000000000003","type":"Stemming","name":"Drill Cuttings","dateCreated":"2019-08-23T05:22:51.7050657Z","dateModified":"2019-08-23T05:22:51.7050657Z","dateDeleted":null,"isDeleted":false,"abbreviation":null,"supplierName":null,"shotPlusReference":null,"restrictedTo":[],"metadata":{},"documentLinks":[]},{"EType":"ProductSave"}]
```

I have tried like below. Convert my DF to an RDD and using spark.read.json read the RDD

```
 val newRDD = MyDF.rdd.map(_.getString(0))
        val ExpectedDF1 = spark.read.json(newRDD.toString())
        ExpectedDF1.printSchema()
```

When printing the schema {"EType":"ProductSave"} this field is missing

Where as other fields are proper.

```
1) val newRDD = MyDF.rdd.map(_.getString(0))
        val ExpectedDF1 = spark.read.json(newRDD.toString())
        ExpectedDF1.printSchema()


2) val newRDD = MyDF.rdd.map(row=> (row.getAs[Json](1).toString))
 val tempDF= spark.read.json(newRDD)
tempDF.printSchema()

3)
        val JsonDF = MyDF.toJSON.toDF("value")
        val convertedRDD = spark.read.json(JsonDF.rdd)
        convertedRDD.printSchema()
```

All these three ways leaving the last field in the schema.
 {"EType":"ProductSave"}

Actual schema returned

```
root
 |-- abbreviation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateCreated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateDeleted: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateModified: string (nullable = true)
 |-- density: double (nullable = true)
 |-- displayColor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- documentLinks: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- isDeleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dateModified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isDeleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- isDeleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- restrictedTo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- shotPlusReference: string (nullable = true)
 |-- supplierName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)


Expected Schema 

root
 |-- EType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- abbreviation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateCreated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateDeleted: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dateModified: string (nullable = true)
 |-- density: double (nullable = true)
 |-- displayColor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- documentLinks: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- isDeleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- dateModified: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isDeleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- isDeleted: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- restrictedTo: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- shotPlusReference: string (nullable = true)
 |-- supplierName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you give `MyDF.printSchema()` and `MyDF.rdd.map(_.getString(0)).take(1)` output

Comment: The input string is not a single JSON. If you copy the entire text and paste in any JSON editor like jsonlint.com and validate it.  It seems like two JSON objects.

Comment: @SMaZ

MyDF.PrintSchema Gives 

root
|--Value: String (Nullable)

Comment: @Ravi

Checked it in https://jsonlint.com/ and it shows valid Json

Comment: Achieved my requirment by Regex replace 

"documentLinks":[]},{"EType":"ProductSave"}

to 

"documentLinks":[],"EType":"ProductSave"}

Comment: Anyways thanks for your replies